# Django: _meta.get_fields() : include_parents=False : Shows fields derived from inheritance

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    """
    Default Common Variables In Database
    """

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by",
                                   null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified_by",
                                    null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_deleted_by",
                                   null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    deleted_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Article(CommonModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    intro_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=doc_hash)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
```

I am trying the following in ipython

```
> Article._meta.get_fields()

(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: created_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: modified_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: deleted_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_deleted>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: created_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: deleted_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: modified_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: title>,
 <django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField: intro_image>,
 <django.db.models.fields.TextField: description>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: url>,
 <django.db.models.fields.SlugField: slug>
```

I try with `include_parents=False`

```
> Article._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)

(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: created_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: modified_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: deleted_by>,
 <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: is_deleted>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: created_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: deleted_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: modified_date>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: title>,
 <django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField: intro_image>,
 <django.db.models.fields.TextField: description>,
 <django.db.models.fields.CharField: url>,
 <django.db.models.fields.SlugField: slug>
```

It shows the same results.

I think it should not show the fields inherited from the `CommonModel`

Can some explain what does `include_parents=False` in this case will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields)

- *include_parents*:

  > `True` by default. Recursively includes fields defined on parent classes. If set to `False`, `get_fields()` will only search for fields declared directly on the current model. Fields from models that directly inherit from abstract models or proxy classes are considered to be local, not on the parent.

In your case, the `CommonModel` declared as `abstract` model. So, all your fields in the `CommonModel` considered as local fields. I think that why you have the same results.

Comment: So here `parent` refers to `inheratance` from `non abstract` classes, hence `include_parents=False`